# How could a planetoid located at L2 appear similar to our moon?

Tags: science-based, astronomy, orbital-mechanics

An Earth-like planet has two moons. One is a natural satellite similar to ours which causes tides and eclipses. The second is an artificial planetoid sitting at Lagrange point L2, the relic of an ancient empire. Due to its position the planetoid always rises a set time after sunset. From the surface of the planet the planetoid appears similar to our moon and even has phases.

What would be the necessary radius to appear this size? What is the upper limit on its mass to be caught within L2 and is the resulting density feasible? Could the planetoid rotate under its own gravity? What surface composition would result in one side appearing bright and the other dark?

Comment: Do you want to ask about the mass/density of the pseudo-moon, or its affects on the planet? Right now your title and question don't match. Also, the L2 point is unstable, so anything there will slowly drift away unless there's a corrective force. Do you have an explanation in your setting for why the pseudo-moon stays put?

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to meet all these constraints at once.

The Earth-Sun L2 point is about 1.5 million km from Earth, around four times the distance of the Moon. So for your L2 planetoid to cause the same tides as the moon, it would have to have about 16 times the mass, which is about 0.2 Earth masses, or nearly twice the mass of Mars. I'm pretty sure that's too massive for the rules for Lagrangian points to apply in a simple manner.

The instability of the L2 point is also a crucial problem. The only way to stay at an L2 point is to have some means of correcting your course, by applying acceleration. Spacecraft at L2 do this with small rocket engines. It doesn't need a huge amount of acceleration, but spacecraft have tiny masses in comparison with planetoids, even small ones.

The only way your fake moon can stay in position is if some extremely powerful alien species, magical force, or other extraordinary means is managing its position, continually.

Comment: Such an artificial planetoid can be relatively low mass, e.g. mostly hollow, allowing it to remain at L2 with modest energy needs to account for the influence of its own mass and the pull of other celestial bodies. As such, it would not influence tides, but it could be sufficiently large to appear visually as a moon.